# AWS CodeBuild - How to show Error test classes in case of unhandled exception from JUnit5 BeforeAll?

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, aws-codebuild

If there is an unhandled exception from JUnit5 `BeforeAll` like below then AWS Code Build is not able to show the failure test classes.

```
class ApiImplTest {
  @BeforeAll
  public static void beforeClass() {
    ...
    throw new RuntimeException("Dummy test error");
  }

  @Test
  void testApi() {
    ...
  }
}
```

AWS Code Build Report is showing like below

[image]

surefire xml report is showing the error like below

```
  <testcase name="" classname="com.master.apis.analytics.ApiImplTest" time="0.002">
    <error type="java.lang.RuntimeException"><![CDATA[java.lang.RuntimeException: Dummy test error
        at com.master.apis.analytics.ApiImplTest.beforeClass(ApiImplTest.java:46)
]]></error>
```

I guess it is due to the `testcase name=""` in the above xml report.

Can someone let me know is there a way to show the failed test class name in the AWS Code Build test report?

- Maven Surefire - 3.0.0-M5
- OpenJDK 11
- Junit-Jupiter - 5.6.3

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using an old version of junit jupiter ? Current version 5.8.2 (5.9.0-M1 available).. ? Also why not using maven-sureifre-plugin version 3.0.0-M6 ?

Comment: Can you explain why you are failing in a BeforeAll ? No tests in your class?

Comment: There are other tests in my class. That code is just a toy example.

Comment: I tried with latest version of junit jupiter and surefire plugin there also I was seeing the same issue. So we did not plan to upgrade them as of now.

Comment: Why is the exception in the beforeall ? That makes no sense... ? BeforeAll runs before any test and meaning that produces an exception!

Comment: Yes in BeforeAll we setup the tests and sometimes there are exception/errors in setting up the test.